# How to set the url of href in nodes?

Tags: jquery, jstree

Does anyone know how can I set the href url of the links node in the jstree?

today it's `href="#"`.

Comment: Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Do you use UI plugin? Can you provide code? jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("your-link-selector").attr("href","new-url-you-want");
```

Comment: Dear Javad, i'm using json object, how should I add the url in my structure?

Comment: can you post your json serializer and deserializer methods above? I should know your object and methods that ser and deser it to help you

Comment: I can't send the generated json object, given a simple json object, how sould I set the url of the nodes links in the json object structure?

Answer (score 0):

You must clarify further, what kind of change you wish to apply to the jstree.
The anchors in the jstree are **not** true anchors who serve the common purpose of changing a web page address, but are merely baits for javascript 'click' event so that various tree action could be executed.

Comment: Hi Nir, what I'm actually want to achieve is to attach URL for each node in my tree so that on node's double-click I will redirect the user to the right page in my site.

Answer (score 0):

simple, just change the data key to an object:

```
    // `data` can also be an object
"data" : { 
    "title" : "The node title", 
    // omit when not needed
    "attr" : {}, 
    // if `icon` contains a slash / it is treated as a file, used for background
    // otherwise - it is added as a class to the <ins> node
    "icon" : "folder"
},
```